On central simple algebras and the Wedderburn Artin's theorem
I learned about the Wedderburn Artin's theorem, says that if $R$ is simple left Artinian ring then $R\cong\mathrm{M}_n(\Delta)$, for some division ring $\Delta$.
Now, I was studying the Brauer group. I need a result that if $A$ is a finite dimensional central simple algebra, then $A\cong\mathrm{M}_n(\Delta)$, for some finite dimensional central division algebra $\Delta$.
I have following question:

The definition of divison algebra is ''Let $\Delta$ is a division ring with center $k$, then $\Delta$ can be regarded as an $k$-algerba, then we say $\Delta$ is a division $k$-algerba''. Am I correct?

Is the result $A\cong\mathrm{M}_n(\Delta)$, for some finite dimensional central division algebra $\Delta$, comes from Wedderburn Artin's theorem? It seems that I need to say that a central simple algebra is an simple left Artinian ring. But I don't know how to explain that it's Artinian. Or maybe I misunderstand something.


For 2: Let $A$ is finite dimensional simple F-algebra with $1_A$ (i.e. finite dimesional $F$-vector space)(Asumming the existensce of $1_A$, since the definition of central simple algerba contains $1_A$) , where F is a field. Consider the decending chain of left ideal of $A$
$$A=M\supset M_1\supset M_2\supset M_3\supset ...$$
Note that $M_i$ is also F-subalgerba of $A$ (i.e. finite dimesional $F$-subspace of $A$), and since $A$ is finite dimesional vector space thus the descending chain will terminate. Therefore, $A$ is left artinian ring.
Thanks for your help!

I think $A$ being Artinian should follow from the fact that $A$ is finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ (namely, its center). Indeed, any descending chain of left ideals of $A$ is also a chain of $F$-vector spaces, which are each finite dimensional because $A$ is. The chain must terminate at some point because the $F$-dimension of each ideal in the chain can't decrease indefinitely - you either have to stabilize or hit $0$.

@AlexWertheim An argument which is a bit easier to write down formally: any nonempty collection of left ideals must have a minimal element, namely a left ideal of minimal dimension.

Thanks for your help, I edit the proof of part 2, is there any other problem in my arguement?
